# Specific css prescription

Tags: html, css

I need a css prescription for a specific problem. I have created image for better understanding.

[image]

I have text (lyrics) separated into individual characters. Every character is wrapped in span.offset. Character can have a chord attached to it. Chord must be displayed above related character. The thing I want to archive is that span.offset will adjusts its width to wider one of offset or char spans.

I came up with the following prescription

html:

```
<p class="line">
    <span class="offset">
        <span class="chord">Am</span>
        <span class="char">A</span>
    </span>
    ...
</p>
```

css:

```
p.line {
    width: 100%;
}

span.offset {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

span.chord {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: -1.5em;
}

span.char {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

This adjusts just for span.chord width. If chord is absent, characters will overlay itselfs.

Is possible to archive behaviour I need? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried changing span.char position to relative?

Comment: You should avoid using floating on the inner elements `.chord` and `.char`, simply because they will be taken out of the document flow, thereby causing the parent (`.offset`) to collapse. In fact, there is no need to use float for the inner elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem:

- **offset** may or may not contain **chord** element
- **char** must be aligned with the bottom in either case
- absolute positioning cannot be used for top/bottom alignment because widths must be same as that of wider child

Solution:

- Create room for chord element whether it is present or not
- Float the chord element left and use negative margin to push it above the char element

```css
p {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #FF0;
}
.offset {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 1.5em;
  margin-right: 1em;
  background: #FC0;
}
.chord {
  float: left;
  margin-top: -1.5em;
  background: #0FC;
}
.char {
  display: block;
  background: #0CC;
}
```

```html
<p class="line">
  <span class="offset">
    <span class="chord">Am</span>
    <span class="char">A</span>
  </span>
  <span class="offset">
    <span class="chord">A</span>
    <span class="char">Am</span>
  </span>
  <span class="offset">
    <span class="char">A</span>
  </span>
</p>
```